# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add the onClick method `front()` to my Button. However when I click on the Button it returns this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method front(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'front'
```

Here's my xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:onClick="front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text" />
```

Register.java:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button front;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        front = (Button) findViewById(R.id.front);
    }

    private void front(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I suggest you that setting an `onClickListener` directly in code is the best way, it never fails and you don't need to declare so many functions in the main code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `front method` in your activity should be **public**. You have made it private right now.

This is described in [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) site too.

> In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter

```
public void front(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: and don't "instant run" (Apply changes), it won't be effected. Unless you Run 'app' (Shift +F10)

Answer (score 11):

Be sure to write the grammar of the attribute value **onClick** correctly. In my case I was forgetting the character **}**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onItemClick(position)}">
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

This is how a click action is given to button through activity.

```
front.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

To give button action through xml `onClick`,

```
public void front(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: that method is also correct. you can define click in xml too